# Messages are not displaying when i uses ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I wanna display success message after calling this method on row edit in data table but it's not displaying for me.Please help

```
  public String onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
             FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(((SearchMaintenanceFields) event.getObject()).getFieldName(), "has been updated Successfully");
             FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
             setUpdateFlag(true); 
             return "searchMaintenance.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
        }
```

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" onstart="PF('dlg').show();" oncomplete="PF('dlg').hide();" listener="#{vaultSearchMaintenanceFields.onRowEdit}"
  update="fieldListTable" />
```

fieldListTable id of data table where i kept this ajax call

Comment: You are redirecting after updating a row which is only needed, when a synchronous POST request is made. What is the purpose of Ajaxical (asynchronous) post back then?

Comment: @Tiny i tried by removing that redirect also but didn't gave me the result

Comment: Create an [mcve]. Wrong combinations like Tiny mentioned and missing message(s) tags are not helpful in debugging

Comment: Where is a `p:message` or `p:messages`?

Comment: Already there in form @opfau

Comment: Try `autoUpdate="true"` for the `p:messages`

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me:

```
public void addMessage(String summary, FacesMessage.Severity severity) {
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(severity, summary, null);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
}
```

Comment: You have been specified severity and summary .with out using them also it's working for me in two cases but i'm facing this issue only in case of ajax call for rowedit event